# `GetUserByAccountError` On Next-Auth with Firebase Adapter

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js

I am trying to create auth system with `next-auth` when I try to log in I got `[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR]  https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information. Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.`. Error log is shown below

```js
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github"
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@auth/firebase-adapter"
import firebaseConfig from '@/lib/firebase.config.json'
import * as firebase from '@firebase/app-compat'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import { Adapter } from "next-auth/adapters"

const app = (
  firebase.default.apps[0] ?? firebase.default.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
)

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_WEB_SECRET as string,
    }),
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    })
  ],
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter(app) as Adapter,
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV != "production"
}

const auth = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { auth as POST, auth as GET }
```

### Error Log

```
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information. Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
    at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:207:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async GoogleAuth.getClient (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:624:17)
    at async GrpcClient._getCredentials (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\grpc.js:145:24)
    at async GrpcClient.createStub (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\grpc.js:308:23)
Caused by: Error
    at Query._get (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1738:23)
    at Query.get (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1726:21)
    at getOneDoc (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:256:52)
    at getUserByAccount (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:123:35)
    at _callee2$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/errors.js:301:43)
    at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:36:24)
    at Generator.eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:123:25)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:64:29)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:4:28)
    at _next (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:17)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:27:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:19:16)
    at Object.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:42:49)
    at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:202:38)
    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:50:30)
    at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:85:24)
    at async C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62591
Caused by: Error
    at Query._get (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1738:23)
    at Query.get (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1726:21)
    at getOneDoc (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:256:52)
    at getUserByAccount (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:123:35)
    at _callee2$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/errors.js:301:43)
    at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:36:24)
    at Generator.eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:123:25)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:64:29)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:4:28)
    at _next (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:17)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:27:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:19:16)
    at Object.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:42:49)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:202:38)
    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:50:30)
    at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:85:24)
    at async C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62591
Caused by: Error
    at Query._get (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1738:23)
    at Query.get (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1726:21)
    at getOneDoc (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:256:52)
    at getUserByAccount (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:123:35)
    at _callee2$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/errors.js:301:43)
    at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:36:24)
    at Generator.eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:123:25)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:64:29)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:4:28)
    at _next (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:17)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:27:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:19:16)
    at Object.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:42:49)
    at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:202:38)
    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:50:30)
    at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:85:24)
    at async C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62591
Caused by: Error
    at Query._get (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1738:23)
    at Query.get (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1726:21)
    at getOneDoc (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:256:52)
    at getUserByAccount (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:123:35)
    at _callee2$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/errors.js:301:43)
    at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:36:24)
    at Generator.eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:123:25)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:64:29)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:4:28)
    at _next (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:17)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:27:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:19:16)
    at Object.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:42:49)
    at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:202:38)
    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:50:30)
    at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:85:24)
    at async C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62591
Caused by: Error
    at Query._get (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1738:23)
    at Query.get (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1726:21)
    at getOneDoc (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@next-auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:267:52)
    at getUserByAccount (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@next-auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:134:35)
    at _callee2$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/errors.js:301:43)
    at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:36:24)
    at Generator.eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:123:25)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:64:29)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:4:28)
    at _next (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:17)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:27:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:19:16)
    at Object.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:42:49)
    at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:202:38)
    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:50:30)
    at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:85:24)
    at async C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62591
Caused by: Error
    at Query._get (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1738:23)
    at Query.get (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1726:21)
    at getOneDoc (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@next-auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:267:52)
    at getUserByAccount (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@next-auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:134:35)
    at _callee2$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/errors.js:301:43)
    at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:36:24)
    at Generator.eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:123:25)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:64:29)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:4:28)
    at _next (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:17)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:27:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:19:16)
    at Object.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:42:49)
    at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:202:38)
    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:50:30)
    at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:85:24)
    at async C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62591
Caused by: Error
    at Query._get (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1738:23)
    at Query.get (C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1726:21)
    at getOneDoc (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:256:52)
    at getUserByAccount (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/firebase-adapter/index.js:123:35)
    at _callee2$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/errors.js:301:43)
    at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:36:24)
    at Generator.eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:123:25)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:64:29)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:4:28)
    at _next (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:17)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:27:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:19:16)
    at Object.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:42:49)
    at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:202:38)
    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:50:30)
    at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:85:24)
    at async C:\Users\happer\Projects\appsmap\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62591 {
  name: 'GetUserByAccountError',
  code: undefined
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error, did you ever find the solution to this problem?

Comment: I think we have to use `firebase-admin` for ssr